# What would be the most efficient method of creating a unit converter whereby the user can scroll through two lists of unit options (side-by-side)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uistackview

I am trying to create a unit converter in Xcode (Swift) and have been trying to get the UI sorted in storyboard. I have been trying to place two table views side-by-side in the top half of the screen to hold two scrolling lists of measurement types and then place a calculator style button display at the bottom of the screen.

I have tried various options and have hit a bit of a wall. Any ideas on the best way to go about doing this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two picker views instead, embedded in a single table view. This would look neater than two separate table views.

[image]